# is it possible to implement HandlebarJS in react-native?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, handlebars.js

I have worked on HandlebarJS long ago but not sure if I can implement it in React-Native development, is there a way to do it or if I can use any templating solution for react-native development?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Just learn react, there is a reason that people have moved on from Handlebar.

Comment: Yes, You can use handlebars in react-native : ref : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-handlebars

Comment: Importing the library directly works: `import Handlebars from 'handlebars/lib/handlebars'`